# Best approach to load Azure Secrets in a .NET application

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, azure-keyvault, polly

I'm trying to find the best solution to reload Azure Secrets in a .NET 5 application. I will write here what I have now.
First I did this:

```
.ConfigureAppConfiguration((context, configuration) =>
{
    var configurationRoot = configuration.Build();

    config.AddAzureKeyVault(
        new Uri(configurationRoot["KeyVault:Uri"]),
        new DefaultAzureCredential()
});
```

But, there is a problem. Secrets are cached until `IConfigurationRoot.Reload()` is called. Expired, disabled, and updated secrets in the key vault aren't respected by the app until Reload is executed or if `ReloadInterval` is used as an option in `AddAzureKeyVault`.

My second approach was to add an interval to reload the secrets automatically every 15 minutes. (And use `IOptionsSnapshot` instead of `IOptions` to get the most recent values)

```
.ConfigureAppConfiguration((context, configuration) =>
{
    var configurationRoot = configuration.Build();

    int reloadInterval;
    bool success = int.TryParse(configurationRoot["KeyVault:ReloadInterval"], out reloadInterval);
    config.AddAzureKeyVault(
        new Uri(configurationRoot["KeyVault:Uri"]),
        new DefaultAzureCredential(),
        new AzureKeyVaultConfigurationOptions()
        {
            ReloadInterval = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(success ? reloadInterval : 15)
        });
});
```

I still think that is not the best solution, because there is still a time window (in this example 15 minutes) in which the secrets in Azure can be changed and if I try to use them I will not have the latest version.
So, I tried a solution where I manually call `IConfigurationRoot.Reload()` when I have an error about an invalid secret.
For example in `MongoDbContext`, if the connection string is invalid I will get a `MongoConfigurationException`.
Using `Polly` I did this:

```
public MongoDbContext(IOptionsSnapshot<DatabaseSettings> databaseSettings, ILogger<MongoDbContext> logger)
{
    _logger = logger;
    _databaseSettings = databaseSettings.Value;

    _policy = Policy
        .Handle<MongoConfigurationException>()
        .Retry(1, (exception, retryCount) =>
        {
             // Reload configuration
        });
    _policy.Execute(() => _mongoClient = new MongoClient(_databaseSettings.ConnectionString));

    _mongoDatabase = _mongoClient.GetDatabase(_databaseSettings.DatabaseName);
}
```

Or maybe this one is better:

```
{
    _logger = logger;
    _databaseSettings = databaseSettings.Value;

    _circuitBreakerPolicy = Policy
        .Handle<MongoConfigurationException>()
        .CircuitBreaker(1, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10));
    _retryPolicy = Policy.Handle<MongoConfigurationException>()
        .Retry(1, (exception, retryCount) =>
        {
             // Reload configuration
        });
    _policy = Policy.Wrap(_retryPolicy, _circuitBreakerPolicy);
    _policy.Execute(() => _mongoClient = new MongoClient(_databaseSettings.ConnectionString));

    _mongoDatabase = _mongoClient.GetDatabase(_databaseSettings.DatabaseName);
}
```

But, with this approach it means that I should do the same thing and catch that specific exception everywhere in the application where I use a secret. Also, I wasn't yet able to inject `IConfigurationRoot` in this class and I don't know if is OK to do that.  `MongoDbContext` is part of the Infrastructure project outside the WebApi project.

Comment: It depends. If you have, let's say less than five, downstream systems then this approach could work. All you need to do is to add `.Or<XYZException>`s. If the downstream system does not throw exception then you can use `HandleResult` with `OrResult` method calls.

Comment: If you have more than that I would recommend to consider a notification based approach. Whenever a state of a secret changes then you can issue a notification. I'm not familiar with Azure's Vault solution but I have found [this article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/key-vault/general/event-grid-tutorial) which shows how to set this up.

Comment: If your keys or secrets are rotating that often, Key Vault alone may not be a suitable choice. You'd want something event driven as well. Certificate rotation can fire Event Grid events, for example. But I'm curious as to why your secrets are changing that often. That's not a common scenario I've heard. It's generally for more durable keys/tokens where you could have primary and secondary keys/tokens that rotate on an offset to make it easier to handle.

Answer (score 0):

Use  [Azure.Extensions.AspNetCore.Configuration.Secrets](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Azure.Extensions.AspNetCore.Configuration.Secrets)
to load the Azure secrets in .NET application

An overload of `AddAzureKeyVault` that takes an `AzureKeyVaultConfigurationOptions` parameter and allows specifying the reload interval.

```
configurationBuilder.AddAzureKeyVault(new AzureKeyVaultConfigurationOptions 
{ 
    Vault = configuration["KeyVaultUrl"], 
    ReloadInterval = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(10), 
});
```

OR you may try with this

Update the `AddAzureAppConfiguration` method to set up a refresh interval for your Key Vault certificate using the `SetSecretRefreshInterval` method. With this change, your application will reload the public-private key pair for ExampleCertificate every 12 hours.

```
config.AddAzureAppConfiguration(options => 
{ 
    options.Connect(settings["ConnectionStrings:AppConfig"]) 
            .ConfigureKeyVault(kv => 
            { 
                kv.SetCredential(new DefaultAzureCredential()); 
                kv.SetSecretRefreshInterval("TestApp:Settings:KeyVaultCertificate", TimeSpan.FromHours(12)); 
            }); 
});
```

For more details refer this [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-app-configuration/reload-key-vault-secrets-dotnet)